# Find String with row, column number from Datatable in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

Im reading excel sheet having two section as input and output section and import that to two Datagridview one for input and another one for Output section in VB.net 2008 Windows application.

If i have 10 rows and 10 columns for input section, then in  my 11th row i have a text like 'End of Input Data' like the same i have in 11th column.

So by checking this,if i get the row and column number of this string i can import the data in to two data grid views. i can import only these row and column data in input gridview.
Below is the code for reading excel sheet. I don't know how to find string in Datatable. Or is there any other way to do that?

```
Private Sub ImpGrid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImpGrid.Click       

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim conStr As String, sheetName As String

    Dim filePath As String = "C:\SIG.XLS"
    Dim extension As String = ".xls"

    conStr = String.Empty
    conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"""      

    Using con As New OleDbConnection(conStr)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
            Using oda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                ' cmd.CommandText = (Convert.ToString("SELECT * From [") & sheetName) + "]"
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Sheet1$]"
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                oda.SelectCommand = cmd
                oda.Fill(dt)
                con.Close()

                'Populate DataGridView.
                Loggridview.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will returns a list of hits. Each result is a Tuple with Item1 being the rowId and Item2 being the columnId

```
Public Structure SearchHit

    Public ReadOnly RowIndex As Integer
    Public ReadOnly CellIndex As Integer

    Public Sub New(rowIndex As Integer, cellIndex As Integer)
        Me.RowIndex = rowIndex
        Me.CellIndex = cellIndex
    End Sub

End Structure

Public Function FindData(ByVal value As String, table As DataTable) As List(Of SearchHit)
    Dim results As New List(Of SearchHit)
    For rowId = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim row = table.Rows(rowId)
        For colId = 0 To table.Columns.Count - 1
            Dim cellValue = row(colId)
            If value.Equals(cellValue) Then
                results.Add(New SearchHit(rowId, colId))
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return results
End Function
```

Comment: Tuple is not defined error is coming. I'm having VS2008, .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: I've updated the code to pass back a custom response instead of the tuple.